# Will Air 1.5 include an update of WebKit with CSS animations?

Tags: jquery, air, webkit

I'm currently developing an html/ajax air app and am about to invest some effort into making animations using jQuery. I could do this quite a bit easier using the css animations if air had that recent a version of WebKit.

I know some people have alpha/beta versions of air 1.5. If you do, can you let me know?

Answer (score 1):

squirrelfish isn't available on safari releases as of yet, so i think it's safe to say if AIR 1.5 is using a webkit build with squirrelfish, it will support at least (if not more) of the CSS capabilities of the latest safari browser.

slightly off-topic, any idea if AIR 1.5 has squirrelfish extreme though?

Comment: I don't know if they've updated the Webkit in later beta builds, but the one I've been using is standard SF.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know offhand what AIR 1.5's CSS capabilities are, but it is a build with SquirrelFish, if that helps you track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR 2.0 Beta has CSS animation [look here](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/AIR_2:Release_Notes#New_Features_in_AIR_2)